# Perl: Using a conditional with an array

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, syntax, conditional-statements

So I'll start of by saying I'm not very familiar with Perl. I have a project that I've been handed at work that requires quite a bit of Perl work. Most of it makes sense but I'm stuck on a very simple issue.

I've simplified my code for example purposes. If I can get this to work I can code the rest of the project no problem, but for some reason I can't seem to get something as simple as the following to work for me:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
@names = ('Harry','Larry','Moe');
foreach $name (@names){
    if($name == 'Harry'){
        print $name;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: fyi the output of the above is the following:

```
HarryLarryMoe
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

String comparisons in Perl aren't done with `==` but with `eq`. Perl is does not consider the integer `13` different than the string `'13'` until you operate on them. [String values that don't represent numbers in any obvious way (e.g. `'Harry'`) are coerced to a numeric value of zero](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values).  Thus, `$name=='Harry'` will always hold, but `$name eq 'Harry'` won't.

Take a look at [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) for more information.

**Edited to add:**  If you had enabled the `warnings` pragma, then the interpreter would have pointed this out to you.  In fact, it's **always** a good idea to [`use strict`](http://p3rl.org/strict) and [`use warnings`](http://p3rl.org/warnings) in pretty much any Perl code that you write.  In particular, this code (executed as a one-liner from the command line via `perl -e`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @names=("Harry","Larry","Moe");

foreach my $name(@names)
{
  if($name=="Harry")
  {
    print "$name\n";
  }
}
```

produces the output

```
Argument "Harry" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 7.
Argument "Harry" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 7.
Harry
Argument "Larry" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 7.
Larry
Argument "Moe" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 7.
Moe
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you so much! And thanks for the tip on strict and warnings. Will defiantly add and start using.

Comment: @JoeBurton - You're more than welcome.  I'd also recommend getting your hands on a copy of [Learning Perl](http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Perl-Randal-L-Schwartz/dp/1449303587), [Programming Perl](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Perl-Unmatched-processing-scripting/dp/0596004923/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334179061&sr=1-1) and/or [Modern Perl](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/) (the latter of which is free).

Comment: Well, maybe other coders in his company don't `use strict` and `use warnings` when coding in Perl...  :P

Answer (score 1):

It is this way because you use numerical comparison but should use string one (`eq`). `$name` and `Harry` evaluate both to 0, so your comparision is in your example always true.